# couchbase php windows client

Tags: php, windows, couchbase

I just fail to understand why couchbase does not provide a php extension for use on "windows" & IIS 7. Is there some efficient other ways of connecting & working with couchbase using php on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Couchbase client SDKs are quite important because they are "cluster aware".

The SDKs, including the PHP one will automatically use all the nodes of the cluster using vBuckets and they will be notified when the topology changes (add new nodes, failover, ...)

Also if you are using Couchbase 2.0 the SDK provides you API to call the views and do more advanced queries on documents.

So the best practice is to use the PHP SDK, that use internally the memcached protocol.

I am inviting you to read:
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/couchbase-clients.html
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-introduction-architecture-vbuckets.html vBuckets used to manage the auto-sharding.
- http://www.couchbase.com/develop/php/next the PHP SDK main page

A more advanced topic that explains how to developer a client SDK:
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/creating-client-library.html

Comment: You are right, I am having trouble using the buckets using memcached client. I'll give this a try. Thanks & upvoted your answer.

Comment: Another approach is to use Moxi a proxy for Couchbase using Memcached protocol but the PHP SDK is definitively better. (see http://www.couchbase.com/docs/moxi-manual-1.8/moxi-introduction.html )

Answer (score 3):

I just set up the Couchbase client library today (PHP 5.4 NTS under IIS7). The directions posted at [Couchbase's page for the PHP Client Library](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/php/getting-started) are accurate for the most part but I wanted to clarify where the dlls go.

- Download the zip containing `php_couchbase.dll` and `libcouchbase.dll`. Generally you will want the [NTS (non-thread safe) version](http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/php/php_couchbase-1.1.2-5.4-nts-vc9-x86.zip) under IIS.
- Put `php_couchbase.dll` in the extensions directory.
- Put `libcouchbase.dll` in the php directory (same directory as `php.exe`/`php-cgi.exe`).
- If necessary, install the [Visual C 9 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) from Microsoft.
- Enable the extension in php.ini

I initially put `libcouchbase.dll` in the extensions folder per the directions on the Couchbase site. That will not work. (Generates the PHP "the specified module could not be found" dll load error.)

The above only gives you the Couchbase client. You also need a server; that can be locally on the Windows machine or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to Couchbase 1 (and not the 2.0 version which is currently in Beta).

[Couchbase is compatible with memcached](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/features#cache). That means you can use any memcached-compatible client to access it, e.g. PHP's [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) functions.

**Update:**

If you want to get your hands dirty and compile the PHP extention for the Couchbase SDK yourself, [here is a tutorial](http://trondn.blogspot.de/2012/11/building-php-extension-for-couchbase-on.html) that guides you through the process.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am talking about Couchbase 1.8.1 the latest download. I am going to try with memcached to see if it works.. Thanks for your answer. I'll mark once this works :) and already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Having trouble using the buckets in couchbase. So am going to try Tug Grall's suggestion.. Let's see.